Nginx - Error Code 111 Connection Refused - Docker + React
I have an application (My SQL, Redis, NGINX, Django, React) with is running on docker. Every file app is running fine where as react is giving 502 Bad Request. I am new to docker.

2024/08/18 07:50:54 [error] 187#187: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 49.36.137.201, server: dev.xxx.in, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4173/favicon.ico", host: "dev.xxx.in", referrer: "https://dev.xxx.in/"

My Docker-compose file is
services:
  npm:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    container_name: npm
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./npm/data:/data
      - ./npm/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_algo_prod
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -h localhost -uroot -prootpassword || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 20

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: pma
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      APACHE_PORT: 9999
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    command: redis-server --loglevel warning --requirepass xxxx
    volumes:
      - ./redis_data:/data

  django:
    build:
      context: backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    container_name: django
    # command: ./manage.py runserver 8080
    command: sh start.sh
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  react:
    build:
      context: frontend
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    container_name: react

and Docker-File is
FROM node:20.14.0-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
CMD ["node_modules/.bin/vite", "preview"]


